# Troubleshooting tweeter speakers on B8.5 Audi S4

Tags: troubleshooting, audi, speakers, fuse-panel, s4

Not sure how long this has been happening for but I’ve noticed that the sound volume and the overall sound intensity has significantly degraded in my 14’ B8.5 Audi S4. So I did a manual sound check (ear to speaker) and concluded that the two front door/corner (tweeter?) speakers are producing zero sound.

[image: Tweeter speaker]

Immediate reaction was to play around with the DSP and some equalizer settings, to make sure the sound focus is not shifted to the back or anything. Everything seemed balanced and I wasn’t able to make them work via settings. Now, few years ago there’s been some work done on the driver’s door due to someone backing into it. Not sure if thats related but I’ve read stories.

Since I feel comfortable doing minor car jobs on my own (done headlight bulb changes etc) but with limited knowledge, how should I tackle this before I go ahead a sell my kidneys to the dealer? Some preliminary thoughts: check for blown fuses (not sure where the fuse box is for these though), try disassembling the door cover and check wiring. Hoping for some wisdom advice from the folks here.

Comment: Do you know which sound system is fitted? If you've got the Prem+ Symphony then there aren't actually any speakers there, there are only speakers in that location on the B&O system IIRC. Obviously this doesn't explain your initial issue, but would explain the lack of sound there in the ear test,

Comment: I know for sure I do not have Bang and Olufsen package as it was much more expensive. If I am not mistaken I have standard technik package. But that would make me happy to know nothing is broken, is this information available anywhere and why do those things look like speakers?

Comment: there are additional speakers installed there when the B&O option is installed - for reasons known only unto themselves Audi chose to put blank fake grilles there on cars that didn't have it. As for the original problem have you done a reboot of the MMI?

Comment: I don’t think Ive tried that, how would I do that?

Comment: Hold the 'Setup', 'Select', and top right (from around the select wheel/button) buttons down simultaneously for a brief moment then release them all and the MMI should restart. Hopefully this will give us a clue as to whether you are having a software or hardware issue.